How to configure a Slack App so that with OAuth it hands back data to a Windows Desktop application?
I manage a C# / .NET Windows Application (Winforms).   For several years, we've had this application rigged up so that users could press a single button to create an MS Teams meeting.  This was done via Azure Portal, where an "application registration" had been set up for our application... and configured properly to handle the authorization.
But we've had to drop the use of MS Teams. We would like to set up similar integration between our app and Slack.
I assumed that I'd need to build an "App" over on the Slack API site, as some of the configuration choices in that looked similar in what I used to see in Azure.  But one thing that I can't figure out is... can a Slack App be rigged so that during the OAuth authorization process, instead of having a "Return_URL" that's an actual webserver URL... it returns back to our Windows Desktop application?   (It looks like Zoom can do this.  We're investigating that too. But I can't seem to find documentation or options that say that Slack can do it? And of course, if so, how to configure it?)
Thanks!
